# What is the maximum volume of a parallelepiped inscribed between two elliptic paraboloids?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Find maximum volume of a parallelepiped inscribed between two elliptic paraboloids $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\pm\frac{z\pm c}{c}, -c\le z\le c$.

I need to use Lagrange multipliers method here.

So

$L = xyz + \alpha_1(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z}{c}-1) + \alpha_2(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z}{c}+1)$

I'm replacing $xyz$ with $ln(xyz)$ so it would be easier to calculate derivatives.

$dL = (\frac{1}{x}+2\frac{x}{a^2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2))dx + (\frac{1}{y}+2\frac{y}{b^2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2))dy + (\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{c}(\alpha_2-\alpha_1))dz$

These partial derivatives also form a system from which I got (it turned out quite messy):

$(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) = -\frac{c}{z+c}$

$(\alpha_2-\alpha_1) = -\frac{c}{z}$

$\alpha_1^2+2\alpha_1=\alpha_2^2$

Also

$d^2L = (-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{a^2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2))dx^2 + (-\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{2}{b^2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2))dy^2 + (-\frac{1}{z^2})dz^2$

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Now I need to find points of max or min and plug them into $d^2L$ to determine if it is positive or negative definite. Could somebody please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you reduce your problem to the case where your elliptic paraboloids are plainly circular paraboloids (paraboloids of revolution) by a shrinking along one of the dimensions ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess it's possible.. could you please explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Indeed, if you solve the problem in the reduced case, i.e., find a certain optimal (rectangular) parallelepiped, the ratio "volume of the parallelepiped"/"volume of the remaining space" is kept constant by an affine transform (here of the type $x'=\frac{a}{b}x, y'=y,z'=z$ ) : therefore, if you maximize one, you maximize the other.

Comment: @JeanMarie how do I calculate the "volume of the remaining space"?

Comment: By using the method presented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280612/305862)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for help, I still wonder though is there a way to solve this in 3d? Is my method bad here?